# Extract information from video through HDMI input processing

Tags: video, hdmi, signal-processing

I need to develop a prototype of a device that does the following:

1. Take an HDMI input
2. For each frame extract a small region of the screen. 
   It's a small bar indicating some changing value.
3. Convert this bar length into an int value, say 0-256.
   This can be done in linux once the region is extracted
4. Pass through the HDMI onto the display

Could you please suggest which processor/development board/capture card or any other device that can accomplish this task. I was looking at DaVinci processors and they look like they are capable of this.

Comment: To clarify what the project is: I'm developing an accessory for a computer game - a racing simulator. This device needs an input from the game - g-force applied to the car. Until my device is supported by the game developer I thought it's a good idea to extract it from the screen for the demonstration purpose. So I'm looking for the easiest way to do it.

Comment: For the easiest way to prototype, I would suggest pointing a webcam at the TV, and doing the image recognition on that capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a BlackMagic PCI Express HDMI video capture and pass-through card. As long as the source is not HDCP encrypted, this would be pretty simple, assuming you're OK with Windows as the host (I don't know of Linux drivers.) There are other video capture/edit suites that can do it as well, but generally more expensive (Matrox has some low-end ones for example.)

Comment: "As long as it's not HDCP" is quite a _massive_ caveat in my limited experience, a huge amount of consumer electronics will not emit and/or accept anything less.

Comment: Who says the input value is consumer electronics? It sounds like the OP wants to screen-scrape a meter of some sort, which sounds more like a video system to me.

Comment: It's a PS3 HDMI output, is it normally encrypted?   Should I use then Windows SDK to do the frame capturing? I wonder what the speed would be, each frame is a big chunk of memory, so I wonder at what rate I can be capturing individual frames.

Comment: Jon - Call it intuition, the only one-word oxymoron. @Henry - you're asking if **Sony** are likely to employ content protection? They have some form in this area which a little googling may reveal. And I see you've already accepted this answer which _cannot_ accept HDCP. You might want to pause for thought next time...

Comment: I guess the question is if the BlackMagic PCI Express card is an authorized HDCP device. I couldn't find it on their website. Well, there's always moneyback.

Comment: From what I can gather, Sony only encrypts copy protected Blu-rays; Everything else is unencrypted. I don't think the BlackMagic card is HDCP certified because of of the requirements for HDCP certification is that it must, ["frustrate attempts to defeat the content protection requirements."](http://www.digital-cp.com/files/static_page_files/D6724AFD-9B02-A253-D8D2FE5B1A10F7F7/HDCP_License_Agreement_082207.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a trivial exercise, but would be feasible with modern components.

I am not sure what you eventual project goals are, but you could bring up a prototype using an FPGA. The Xilinx Spartan-6 family, for example, has HDMI input and output capabilities. The [Digilent Atlys Development Board](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS&CFID=84078&CFTOKEN=97412297) seems like it could support your requirements. The board has the HDMI input and output connectors.

As far as processing, I believe that the Xilinx MicroBlaze core (which would run on the FPGA) can support Linux, if you feel an OS is necessary.

A few caveats:

If the HDMI signal is encrypted (HDCP), the task becomes harder.

If your eventual goal is a low cost consumer solution, using an HDMI capable FPGA may be cost prohibitive. An alternative would be to use a dedicated HDMI transmitter and receiver chips and a uC/DSP processor.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, this might be a DMCA violation. (Yes, the laws can be silly.) I'm pretty ignorant of all things HDMI, but you might want to start by reading up on Bunnie's NeTV ("any TV") open source project at http://www.kosagi.com/blog/. That might lead you to the information you need to solve your problems.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. This is more of a caveat, which belongs with the comments to the question. Please repost as a comment, thanks.